# How do i get pixel data of an AWT component?

Tags: java, graphics, components, awt, pixel

I have a JLabel component to which i write some text. I want to decode it to pixel array and send it via RS-232 interface to some external appliance.

How can i access pixels of Component or Graphics objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Robot is one way.  Here is [another way](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.gui/browse_thread/thread/038a6abd670edad9/662e54ff77c3e6f8?pli=1).

Robot is fine for most needs, better for some, but the advantage of the second way is that it can be done even in a sand-boxed app.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't think about this solution - to use components paint() method on image which pixels i can access.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. Here's an example how to [create a screenshot](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/293.html) with it.